# Sql Pivot 2 columnas compuestas

Tags: sql, script, powerbi, pivot

Estoy tratando de hacer un pivot en sql sin lograrlo
tengo una tabla asi
[image: Tabla Original]

intento que quede asi, que los valores de Calificacion se muestren como columnas con su Minimo y Maximo

[image: Tabla final]

Estoy usando este script pero creo que algo anda mal

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

WITH cte AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT b.Nombre as Calificacion
FROM ToleranciaDetalle a
INNER JOIN Calificacion b on a.CalificacionId = b.Id
INNER JOIN Defecto c on a.DefectoId = c.Id
INNER JOIN Categoria d on a.CategoriaId = d.Id
)
SELECT @cols = COALESCE(@cols + ',', '') +
QUOTENAME(Calificacion + ' Minimo') + ',' +
QUOTENAME(Calificacion + ' Maximo')
FROM cte;

SET @query = 'SELECT Nombre as Categoria, ' + @cols + '
FROM
(
SELECT d.Nombre as Nombre,
b.Nombre as Calificacion,
ISNULL(a.Minimo, 0) AS Minimo,
ISNULL(a.Maximo, 0) AS Maximo
FROM ToleranciaDetalle a
INNER JOIN Calificacion b on a.CalificacionId = b.Id
INNER JOIN Defecto c on a.DefectoId = c.Id
INNER JOIN Categoria d on a.CategoriaId = d.Id
) x
PIVOT
(
SUM(Minimo)
FOR Calificacion IN (' + @cols + ')
) p';
EXECUTE (@query);
```

Me arroja Null

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien me da una mano

la consulta

```
SELECT d.Nombre as Nombre, b.Nombre as Calificacion, ISNULL(a.Minimo, 0) AS Minimo, ISNULL(a.Maximo, 0) AS Maximo 
FROM ToleranciaDetalle a INNER JOIN Calificacion b on a.CalificacionId = b.Id 
INNER JOIN Defecto c on a.DefectoId = c.Id INNER JOIN Categoria d on a.CategoriaId = d.Id
```

devuelve

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes agregar que retorna la siguiente consulta:

SELECT d.Nombre as Nombre,
b.Nombre as Calificacion,
ISNULL(a.Minimo, 0) AS Minimo,
ISNULL(a.Maximo, 0) AS Maximo
FROM ToleranciaDetalle a
INNER JOIN Calificacion b on a.CalificacionId = b.Id
INNER JOIN Defecto c on a.DefectoId = c.Id
INNER JOIN Categoria d on a.CategoriaId = d.Id

Creo que el error va por ahí

Comment: @MrDonPh0x me retorna esto
Nombre                              Calificacion Minimo Maximo
==================================
Defectos Mayores Uva             Bueno                1 2
Defectos Mayores Uva             Malo               3 4

Comment: Podrias agregarlo a la pregunta?

Answer (score 0):

El concepto base de los Pivote es que pasan Filas a Columnas,
Por lo que tienes que asegurarte que en este resultado aparezcan los valores que deseas pivotear, en tu caso "Bueno Mínimo", "Bueno Máximo"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que podrías hacer con un Cross Join o un Cross Apply sobre la tabla de Calificacion, para poder tener filas con las clasificaciones que deseas.

Por favor echale un vistaso a la siguiente
[respesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067490/in-sql-server-how-to-pivot-for-multiple-columns) es probable que te pueda servir.

Answer (score 0):

el problema surge en la parte del Pivot

```
x
PIVOT
(
SUM(Minimo)
FOR Calificacion IN (' + @cols + ')
) p'
```

@cols posee las Calificacion concatenadas -->

```
[Bueno Minimo],[Bueno Maximo],[Malo Minimo],[Malo Maximo]
```

y Califiacion posee --> Bueno, Malo

entonces al hacer FOR no encuentra esas columnas y no devuelve los valores